# Add DLL to WPF Application by code

Tags: wpf, dll

I have a project and also have a UserControlLibrary. I have created DLL of UserControlLibary.Now, I want to add it to my application by code.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("user.dll");
        Type myType = a.GetType();
        UserControl user = (UserControl)a.CreateInstance(myType);
        this.main_grid.Children.Add(user);
```

How can i do?

Comment: Doesn't work is to little information, does it throw an exception? If so, please tell us the exception.

Comment: Where does it fail? What's the exception? "Doesn't work" is really vague!

Comment: please change the name of the dll, just to avoid confusing it with the system one

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("DLLName");
Type[] listTypes = assembly.GetTypes();

for (int i = 0; i < listTypes.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("At position "+i+": "+listTypes[i].Name);
```

Then, if your type is listed:

```
Type myType = listTypes[i];
FrameworkElement a = (FrameworkElement)Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
this.main_grid.Children.Add(a);
```